# Comparing large text files

Tags: unix, awk, sed, compare, diff

I have to compare large text files to determine the difference between file1 and file2. Each file is containing domain names. Size of files around: 2GB.

```
Content sample:

domain1.com
domain2.com
```

I would prefer to use unix tool to get the results. Basically I want to output all lines from file1, which are not present in file2. Generally what I am trying to accomplish is to determine the list of expired domains.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There exist tools for that. Even online. Example: http://www.diffnow.com/

Comment: check here:http://theunixshell.blogspot.in/2012/12/i-have-two-files-file-1-contains-3.html or http://theunixshell.blogspot.in/2012/12/file-comparisons-using-awk-match-columns.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first cut I would try the following:

```
comm -13 <( sort file1 ) <( sort file2 )
```

This will give you lines occurring only in file2. You may be surprised how fast this actually is considering how little effort that one-liner is to type.

If this is something you'll be doing frequently, it is a good idea to keep the files sorted, then you can just to the `comm`. If your files contain many duplicates, you may also save some time by doing a `| uniq` after the sort.

Comment: `-12` will return only lines which are present in both files. `-13` will return the lines unique to file2.

Comment: It should indeed be -13, but in a different way: comm -13 <( sort file2 ) <( sort file1 ). @chthonicdaemon kindly edit the answer and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Are you sure about the file order? man comm says the columns are "(1) lines only in file1; (2) lines only in file2; and (3) lines in both files." According to your question you wanted lines only in file2, so we _want_ column 2, meaning we need to hide columns 1 and 3.

Comment: I've edited the answer to do `-13` instead of `-12`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `diff`

```
diff file1 file2
```

Comment: This will not work properly if the files are not sorted, and is slower than `comm` if they are.

Answer (score -1):

Using grep, you can specify a file to read the patterns from (`-f file1`) and negate the output, that is print non-matches, via `-v`:

```
grep -v -f file1 file2
```